# When dependency property is being applied?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm doing some training project right now. It's supposed to convert numbers into different strings.
Heres the converted Control, and in the bottom way I use it in my Main Window.
So the first problem is that I want to create instance of converter based on value I pass to OutputFormatProperty so in this case I create converter that should be type OctalConverter but instead I get the default one, why is that?
Another thing is that I wan't to change InputValue in the converter by binding it to CurrentValue, which works with NotifyPropertyChanged, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

```
public partial class ConverterDisplay : UserControl {

    private const int DEFAULT_INPUT_VALUE = 0;
    private readonly ObservableCollection <DisplayField> _displayFields;
    private AbstractNumberConverter _converter;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register (
        "InputValue",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(ConverterDisplay),
        new PropertyMetadata (DEFAULT_INPUT_VALUE));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register (
        "OutputFormat",
        typeof(NumberSystems),
        typeof(ConverterDisplay),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (NumberSystems.Binary));


    public int InputValue {
        get {
            return (int) GetValue (InputValueProperty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue (InputValueProperty, value);
            UpdateDisplay ();
        }
    }
    public NumberSystems OutputFormat {
        get {
            return (NumberSystems) GetValue (OutputFormatProperty); 

        }
        set {
            SetValue (OutputFormatProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection <DisplayField> DisplayFields {
        get { return _displayFields; }
    }

    public ConverterDisplay () {
        _displayFields = new ObservableCollection<DisplayField> ();
        InitializeComponent ();
        CreateConverter ();
    }

    private void UpdateDisplay () {
        var convertedNumberString = _converter.GetString (InputValue);

        if (_displayFields.Count > convertedNumberString.Length)
            ResetDisplayFields ();

        while (_displayFields.Count < convertedNumberString.Length)
            AddDisplayField ();

        UpdateValues (convertedNumberString);
    }

    private void UpdateValues (string convertedString) {
        if (_displayFields.Count == 0) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < _displayFields.Count; i++) {
            _displayFields [i].NumberValue = convertedString [i];
        }
    }

    private void AddDisplayField () {
        _displayFields.Insert (
            0,
            new DisplayField ((int)OutputFormat, _displayFields.Count));
    }

    private void ResetDisplayFields () {
        _displayFields.Clear ();
    }

    private void CreateConverter () {
        switch (OutputFormat) {
            case NumberSystems.Binary:
                _converter = new BinaryConverter ();
                break;
            case NumberSystems.Octal:
                _converter = new OctalConverter ();
                break;
            case NumberSystems.Hexadecimal:
                _converter = new HexadecimalConverter ();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum NumberSystems {
    Binary = 2,
    Octal = 8,
    Hexadecimal = 16
}
```

And then in the Main Window I'm trying to use that control

```
 <converters:ConverterDisplay x:Name="octConverter"
                              InputValue="{Binding ElementName=Window,Path=CurrentValue}"
                              OutputFormat="Octal"/>
```

Just in case

```
public int CurrentValue {
        get { return _currentValue; }
        set {
            if (value == _currentValue)
                return;
            ValidateNewValue (value);
            OnPropertyChanged ();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
    }
```

===========================

Edit #1

I don't really like that solution but I created public method in ConverterDisplay to create converter, it's being called after MainWindow is initialized so now the converters are correct. 
Another thing is that how do i bind my UpdateDisplay method to InputValueProperty? I found through validation that it's getting correct value, but I can't see way how I can run that method without creating static stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your second problem (binding the `UpdateDisplay` method to `InputValueProperty`: In general, it's not the best idea to call any method within a dependency property's setter, since this setter is never invoked when using data binding to fill the dependency property's value, as pointed out [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The WPF XAML processor uses property system methods for dependency
>   properties when loading binary XAML and processing attributes that are
>   dependency properties. This effectively bypasses the property
>   wrappers. When you implement custom dependency properties, you must
>   account for this behavior and should avoid placing any other code in
>   your property wrapper other than the property system methods GetValue
>   and SetValue.

Instead, create a callback method that is invoked whenever `InputValue`'s content changes, and call `UpdateDisplay` from there:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register (
    "InputValue",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(ConverterDisplay),
    new PropertyMetadata (DEFAULT_INPUT_VALUE, InputValueChangedCallback));


private static void InputValueChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var userControl = dependencyObject as ConverterDisplay;
    if (userControl != null)
        userControl.UpdateDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats how I'll do that, I think that I'll also use this solution to create different NumberConverters when value on OutputFormatProperty changes so I don't have call anything from code inside MainWinow :]